# Remove "Search workspace (cmd+click)" hover from Integrated Terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

Since new update (1.46.0) the floating window appears any time I move my mouse to any string in the Integrated Terminal. It's very annoying to me. 
Can anyone please tell me how do I disable this feature?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMa7D.png)

Answer (score -1):

I assume this commit solved or at least helped this situation https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/832a49d14dc048fc381b51793019e76412cc9452

Can you try out the Insiders' Build to see if it is better (or wait for v1.4).